# "Welcome back" message annoying and not needed

Tags: discussion, bug, status-bydesign, questions

About once a week I get a "welcome back" message that encourages me to 'vote up questions' and won't go away without a click. Is it really necessary to ask people who have been around for 7 years to 'vote up' questions/answers?

That seems needlessly annoying.

Comment: I get this all the time on meta.stackexchange, it doesn't happen here. Kinda surprised Keng is getting it here.

Comment: @TinyGiant, no, I'm usually on throughout the work week.  and Im sure I was on earlier this week but got it again today.

Comment: Hmmm... smells like a bug.

Comment: I would [edit] the question to ask what the triggers for showing this popup are. Then it can be addressed. I don't think removing the popup entirely is a real solution to the problem.

Comment: Yeah, sounds like a bug. I'll edit the question so the team notices

Comment: Well that question deserves an up vote .... just to make sure I don't get that pop up.

Comment: This is mainly an annoyance for my less-frequented SE sites... but it's equally irksome there.

Comment: burniate it please!

Comment: I used to get all sorts of reminders about voting on questions etc. Haven't had one in ages. Maybe it stopped, or maybe it retrained me, who knows?

Comment: @Rizier123 I sure do hope that all those keen on *downvoting all the crap* take the pain to leave comments on **why** they are so keen on downvoting...

Comment: In the past, I primarily upvoted answers when I searched for a solution to a problem. Therefore I also got this reminder regularly. But nowadays I usually upvote the questions too, because without the question I wouldn't have found the answer. So for me, this is not an issue anymore.

Comment: despite all the fun done here, it is *still* annoying, *sigh*

Comment: I get this message about every other visit to any site on SE. And that's not exaggerating much. It feels like it shows every time, but sometimes, few they are, it doesn't. Extremely annoying. Considering enabling adblocking just to block it.

Comment: @Narfanar Same for me, it's ridiculous. Once a week would be fine, but not every visit.

Comment: You can make this obviously dumb UI go away with an adblocker that can permanently block elements like ublock origin:  https://www.ghacks.net/2017/02/21/ublock-origin-how-to-remove-any-element-from-a-page-permanently/.  Wake up, SE UX team!

Comment: I was thinking it's "All questions" category and thought it's new topic and I miss it somehow. Excuse my rant please (now deleted).

Comment: I just received this on a question I had *already voted on child elements.*

Comment: is there still no way to turn this off? it's so annoying ...

Answer (score 28):

[From Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89045/disable-dont-forget-to-vote-message/89059#89059):

> [image: Welcome back! If you found this question useful, don't forget to vote both the question and the answers up.]
>
> The message
>
> > Welcome back! If you found this question useful, don't forget to vote both the question and the answers up.
>
> only appears if
>
> - you haven't been seen on the the target site for 24 hours
> - you hold a valid user cookie on the target site
> - your account has more than 15 rep on the target site
> - you arrive on a question from a search engine
> - you have not already voted on this particular question and answers
>
> Therefore, you shouldn't ever see it more than once per day per site.
>   And if you are on the target site(s) frequently enough you may never
>   see it.

Voting on questions that help you in your research is critical: these votes are a **very strong** signal to the system that the question is relevant and needed. Voting is often overlooked, *especially* on questions; a reminder for folks who infrequently visit is worthwhile.

Note that if you're seeing this banner and *do not* meet the conditions described above, then that is indeed a bug. However under normal circumstances it isn't unusual to run into it when visiting the site from, say, Google after having been away for a day (or weekend...)

Note also that the "time away" appears to have been [increased to 48 hours](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91553/i-see-welcome-back-if-you-found-this-question-useful-message-very-frequent) at some point, so I'd blame weekends under normal circumstances.

Last note: to check the days that the site has seen you, click the "visited..." link on [the "profile" page of your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=profile):

[image]

Comment: It's weird, but I *still* sometimes remember to vote thanks to that popup.  For whatever reason, if I arrive by googling AND am on a site I don't frequent, the lack of vote-muscle-memory on that specific site, plus being mid-problem seems to cause me to forget.

Comment: "you shouldn't ever see it more than once per day per site"....wow...a forced click to clear a message box to give information that I have known about since 2008....hmmmmm.....that is....disappointingly annoying...and more likely (read: certainly) going to get the opposite results than intended. maybe the powers could consider something less asinine like a 3 second delay to clear itself.

Comment: It's been in place for 4 years, @Keng - really, a minor annoyance for a rather critical reason.  If you have suggestions for improvement now that you know how it operates, please post them separately as a [meta-tag:feature-request].

Comment: @Keng all you need to do to avoid the banner is visit the site more.

Comment: So this feature exists for and is made by you @Jaydles?  ;)

Comment: @rene, I wish I could take credit. It pre-dates me, but you're right that eventually, much of our UX will probably devolve into things designed to help me remember stuff I should already know.

Comment: I too find it annoying, but really it is a minor nuisance. What if the ability to turn this off is given as a privilege? IE: If you have 100 rep (or whatever level) an option is now present in settings to turn off this message?

Comment: This answer states that "you shouldn't ever see it more than once per day per site" yet I frequently do.  If I only saw it once a day I would not have been annoyed enough to find this question.  I think that what I do to see it frequently is to search on google, open an SO question, close the "Welcome Back", navigate from a link in the question, use the back button.  Then I see "Welcome Back" again.  If this could be solved I would be SUBSTANTIALLY less annoyed.

Comment: Why does arriving "on a question from a search engine" come into this at all?  Why is that indicative that the user needs information about how to use the site?

Comment: Would it be a good idea to disable this message for users that have some minimum of up votes on questions and answers?  Or perhaps a badge based on up vote counts that allows a user to disable the (annoying) feature? Clearly anyone with 1000 up votes on each doesn't need this instruction.  What is an appropriate threshold?

Comment: @Shog9 Thanks for the informative and seemingly correct answer.  I have upvoted this answer for those reasons.  To those that can change the policies, please make the criteria fit the problem.  I am a long time casual user of the site, and am grateful enough for it that I would like to help you improve the site.  Toward that end I have spent over an hour trying to figure out how to suggest that this "Welcome Back" message be removed.

Comment: @Shog9 I think time has shown that this major annoyance has not helped, and still only pisses off long-time users. I'd love to see your analytics showing that someone who visits less than every 24 hours needs to be reminded that they have an account.

Comment: Could we just use some metrics to see if someone has been trained to upvote stuff? Also, if I open 3-4 questions from google, and I only get the banner once, it's unlikely to appear on the question I want to upvote.

Comment: How about not showing the banner ever if the user has voted a certain number of times or more? I've been on the site a long time and always for for stuff that is helpful, I don't need to be reminded how it works.

Comment: A year and a half later, and this annoying popup is still there. It doesn't remind me to do anything; it's just noise, like all the annoying cookie warnings. They serve no purpose whatsoever except contribute to RSI.

Comment: Ah. "More than 15 reputation". This explains why I suddenly started getting this banner on all stackexchange links I click. After many years I finally got the "yearling" badge that grants 100xp on any site you join. The only option seems to be to disable all stackexchange "overlay-header" elements with a styling extension. Now I won't see any banners :/ Ah well...

Comment: Do you (StackExchange) have metrics that show this popup achieves its goal? It hides the search bar and "Products" buttons, any impact on those? I agree with @Keng : it feels more like a punishment for not visiting the site often enough...

Comment: Yep, still happening. "48 hours" away from the site? That deems it necessary to remind me yet again? I work with StackOverflow every day, but I tend to have weekends off! Do I really need to be reminded because I didn't use Stack Overflow ALL WEEKEND?

Comment: Add me to the list of longtime users who find this to be a major annoyance, not a minor one. Maybe I'm too impatient. I get super-irritated when I visit a site looking for certain info, and *anything*, no matter how small or seemingly unobtrusive, gets in the way and requires me to click it to make it go away. Anyway, like others, I've added a custom style that will permanently hide `#overlay-header`.

Answer (score 15):

I've gotten the pop up if I get to Stack Overflow via a Google search for some issue. I just did a search for "arcobjects GetDesktopWindow memory usage" and got this:

[image: Screenshot of "Welcome back!" message on the GIS stack exchange.]

I was also able to get it on Meta Stack Exchange by searching for something I knew would result in a link to a question there. (Last time I was on Meta was the 5th of October.)

However, I can't seem to make it happen on Stack Overflow on purpose (I obliterated the cache, cookies from Chrome and logged out), although it has happened recently. Perhaps it also has to do with how long it's been since you've voted.

Answer (score 12):

I've just created a user style that hides these annoying overlays that always get in the way of other relevant content. Just like with overlay ads, I hate this kind of UI.

```
#overlay-header
{
    display: none !important;
}
```

This can be applied to all the domains you have an account for, like:

- superuser.com
- stackoverflow.com
- stackexchange.com

For Firefox, I use the Stylus extension.

Comment: Hmm. This will hide _all_ instances of `overlay-header`. What is the chance we may be missing out on other important headers?

Answer (score 10):

At the very least, the message should be reworded to make it more clear that only *useful* answers should be upvoted, instead of:

[image]

How about something like:

> Welcome back! Don't forget to up-vote useful questions and answers.

Or appeal to altruism:

> Welcome back! Help other programmers by up-voting useful questions and answers.

Let's not forget that down-votes are just as important as up-votes.  If the user lacks the privilege, omit the part in brackets:

> Welcome back! Use up-votes [and down-votes] to help other users find the most useful questions and answers.

Answer (score 6):

You can use this userstyle to hide the welcome back message on all Stack Exchange sites: *https://userstyles.world/style/4744/hide-stack-overflow-stack-exchange-welcome-back-message*

This requires a userstyle extension, like [Stylus](https://add0n.com/stylus.html).

Comment: Can you please fix the spelling on *userstyles.world*? It is ***"Stack Overflow"*** and ***"Stack Exchange"***. See for example [this](http://stackoverflow.com/legal/trademark-guidance), section *"Proper Use of the Stack Exchange Name"*.

Comment: @PeterMortensen done