# Please improve the criteria for the "Welcome back" message

Tags: feature-request, design, system-message

The message to a user to remember to vote on questions and answers is a good thing, for those users that do not know to do so.  It is very annoying to many users, as evidenced by [Disable "don't forget to vote" message](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89045) and ["Welcome back" message annoying and not needed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307692).  It would be more helpful if it were targeted at those users who need the information.  I would think that two criteria most appropriate for determining if the message will be helpful to a particular user are

1. The number of question votes cast.
2. The number of answer votes cast.

The criteria used seem to be (based on the accepted answer in the first question above)

1. you haven't been seen on the target site for 24 hours, and
2. you hold a valid user cookie on the target site, and
3. your account has more than 15 rep on the target site, and
4. you arrive on a question from a search engine
5. you have not already voted on this particular question and answers

Criterion 1 targets long time but casual users.  Why 24 hours?  Why not 24 minutes?  Why not 24 days?  I do not feel that I need the instruction.  I use the site less than daily, but enough to know to vote on questions and answers, and enough to be quite annoyed by the "Welcome back" message.  A user that visits your site once a week and votes on 3 questions and answers during that visit doesn't need education about voting.

Criterion 2, if useful, implies that not using cookies is a good indication that the user does not need instruction.  Cookies should simply not be a part of the equation.

Criterion 3 has some merit, but should be a range rather than merely a minimum.  Shouldn't someone with 10k rep not need the message?  What is a good threshold?  And why merely rep when you also know how many votes a user has?

Criterion 4 seems to be of value only in order to discourage use of outside search engines in favor of going to https://www.stackoverflow.com directly.  A person's search habits and styles doesn't seem to me to be a good indication of their knowledge of how to vote on questions and answers.

Criterion 5 is good.  It could be improved by accounting for how likely the user is to vote on a question when appropriate.  This is understandably difficult to measure, since you should not encourage users to vote on questions that were found but not relevant.  But accounting for the number of times the user has voted on questions and answers in general would be an improvement.

I have been using the site casually for about 8 years.  My usage is casual enough that I have a mere 348 rep during that time.  Yet I have more votes than rep points.  I do know how to vote.  I have grown so annoyed at the message that I have spent a good part of a Saturday afternoon to request that you at least tone it down.  Based on the questions referenced above I doubt that I am the only one in a situation similar to this.

At the very least, do not show the message again when I navigate back to a question where I have already dismissed it.

I think a badge earned by voting that permits a user to disable the message would be sufficient to resolve this issue favorably with a vast majority of your users.

Thank you for your consideration.  And a very hearty thank you for providing the Stack Exchange family of sites.  I do find them quite helpful.  I am hoping that your response to this question will make it even more so for me and for others.

---

#### Edit

I originally requested "that you at least tone it down."  The new popup,

[image]

does just that.  Thank you.

In the original post I stated, "I think a badge earned by voting that permits a user to disable the message would be sufficient to resolve this issue favorably with a vast majority of your users."  This remains a good idea, IMHO.

Comment: I hope that posting a "question" of this nature with a tag of "feature-request" is the appropriate way to ask for improvements to StackExchange in general.  If not, please let me know the correct approach for doing so.

Comment: A feature request here is fine. Another potentially effective place is Twitter.

Comment: @Rik, the reference for the comment above is the Twittergate sparked by this big Meta post: [Revisiting the “Hot Network Questions” feature, what are our shared goals for having it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/316941/185667)

Comment: Let me clarify my statement that starts with "At the very least...."  If I do see the "Welcome back" message then close it, then navigate to a link on the page, then navigate back to the question, the message reappears.  If this were not the case I would not have become so motivated to request an improvement regarding the message.

Comment: Number 2 is needed to prevent people who cannot vote from getting the message

Comment: Umm, someone correct me if I'm wrong but I don't think that those are actually the only criteria for displaying that message _currently_. Note: this assessment is based _only_ on my personal experience with the network.

Comment: 24 hours is bafflingly short. That would only really (perhaps) make sense for someone who's visiting the site for literally the first time after creating their account / getting the upvote privilege. A week would make more sense if the user is still pretty new and a month or more would be better if the user is experienced and has been voting plenty before.

Comment: The reasoning behind the rep requirement is presumably because you *can't* vote with less reputation than that. If someone hasn't been on the site for years, you can make a good case that they should be reminded to vote regardless of reputation. Some people get pretty far with just a single post, and others has plenty of posts but not much reputation. I'm not sure there's really an upper limit that would make sense.

Comment: The reasoning behind having them come from a search engine is presumably to target users who *aren't* coming to [so] specifically, but are rather just looking for an answer to their question, to give them like an "oh, right, I have an account here"-kind of moment.

Comment: I don't understand why I'm constantly pestered by this banner. I have 3rd party cookies disabled, which may be a factor, but I use Stack Exchange every day and I don't need a damn banner to remind me to vote. I've just manually added uBlock element filters to remove the banner because I'm so sick of it.

Comment: While this post is the correct way to ask for a change on Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange, you will find, from a personal standpoint, that it's vastly more effective to just create a userscript or style that hides that notification. You would then never be bothered by it again. The reason this would be more effective is that the vast majority of requested changes basically never happen, or take a *long* time to be implemented, even if they take very low development effort (even near-trivial), are highly up-voted, and/or requested multiple times, by multiple people, etc.

Comment: Hey @RikRenich, there's a banner here that says you're a new contributor, so I just thought I'd mention, in case you didn't know, that you can vote on questions and answers here.

Comment: And web devs are always deleting their cookies for testing...

Comment: @Makyen Related: [The Stack Overflow Unofficial Patch (SOUP)](https://stackapps.com/q/4486)

Comment: @Dukeling Thanks for the SOUP link.  If SO needs SOUP then perhaps my question is a waste of my time and those reading it.  Let's hope that's not the case.

Comment: @Dukeling I've been using SOUP for years. It's quite helpful. I wasn't aware that this issue was one which it addressed. I don't see it on the [list of issues fixed](https://github.com/vyznev/soup/blob/master/CONTENTS.md).

Comment: @Makyen I mean that might be a better place to go if you're looking for requested changes that actually happen.

Comment: This is yet another manifestation of the basic problem of the Stack Exchange multi-site/multi-acount architecture. I do not particularly care if the google search brought me to StackOverflow or SuperUser or some other even smaller SE site. I obviously know how to vote because I do it constantly, all day, on Stack Overflow for my job. I do not need to be re-taught how to vote on every other random SE site that I visit less than once every 24 hours.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Welcome back" message annoying and not needed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307692/welcome-back-message-annoying-and-not-needed)

Comment: @10Rep The question you suggest is already referred to in the first paragraph.  My question is an alternative, since teaching/prompting users to vote can be a good thing, if those users could benefit from that teaching or prompting.

Comment: Yes, it's very related, however.